# import assets for unity ARcore application from server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

So i have built an unity augmented reality application but the problem i'm facing that i need to import a diffrent 3d model each time i open the application from an online server any ideas how to do that ?